# Can't recall if I half-assed this

Tags: translation-check

I'm going through some of my older poetry and I found this verse in Latin, which I don't know how to speak or write:

> Suspirat diu ab scapula eius.
>
> Basit ab palmus dorsum eius.
>
> Silentium regnat. Nascitur
>
> pacis mundus.

This is from about nine years ago and I have no memory of it. It's made me curious: Did the younger me go to the trouble of researching this and rendering it correctly? Or is it malformed gibberish? I'm fairly linguistically minded but I'd be surprised if I got a whole 15 correct words in a row on my own. Sadly, I'm not even able to tell how much effort I did or didn't put in.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is mostly but not entirely correctly inflected Latin, but in the first and second lines the words do not really come together into comprehensible sentences:

- in the first sentence, *suspirare* does not usually stand with *ab*, and it is not clear what it is supposed to mean (“sigh away from his/her shoulder” or some such?)
- in the second sentence, *basit* is not a proper word (should probably be *basiat* “kisses,” but then you have the same problem with *ab*), also you have no word agreeing with *ab*, this sentence is more or less gibberish

The third and fourth sentences are fine and mean: “Silence reigns. The world of peace is born.”

In summary I believe it is fair to say you did half-ass it.